# Is it possible to have a small indicator showing that updates are available (red for security updates) instead of having the update manager pop up?

Tags: indicator, update-manager

I'm on ubuntu 12.04 with unity.

I've been googling for an answer to that question for several weeks and found nothing.

What I want is the old behaviour where a small indicator icon shows that there are available updates.

It's very annoying and inelegant to have the update manager pop up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### 12.04 onwards

Newer Ubuntu users can find the settings in **dconf-editor**. Install [dconf-tools](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools)
[image: Install dconf-tools] if necessary.

Then, launch `dconf-editor`, then go to  **com > ubuntu > update-notifier** and **uncheck auto-launch**.

[image: dconf editor]

---

### Older versions of Ubuntu

Open **Configuration Editor** , then go to **apps > update-notifier**, then **uncheck auto-launch**.

[image: gconf editor]

You'll still be able to see

> Updates Available

from System menu accessible from the top-right corner of the screen.

[image: notification icon]

Comment: It doesn't look like that still holds in 18.04 or 20.04.